# Date Created is not going to change while delete file and then create file

Tags: java, file

due to some reason i have to remove older file and create new file according to our client

Date Modified is change to current time but Date Created is not change to current time.

[image]
my code is as follows

```
  public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    FileUtils.deleteQuietly(new File("d:\\inbox\\json\\test.txt"));
    FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter("d:\\inbox\\json\\test.txt", false);
    fileWriter.append(new Date().toString());
    fileWriter.close();
  }
```

this code remove older data and write new data

but why date created time is not changed..

please help me to figure out what's in wrong with my code.
thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry by mistake i put wrong code
now i update code please help me
i have also tried


`// Files.delete(Paths.get("d:\\inbox\\json\\test.txt"));;
// Files.deleteIfExists(Paths.get("d:\\inbox\\json\\test.txt"));`

Comment: please help me why i am getting this problem
is there any changes require in my code??

Comment: i also tried forceDelete but result in same old file created time stamp.
please help.

Comment: i have added delay after delete file
if delay is 15000 then file creation time is changed
and if delay is 14000 then file creation time is not changed.

why system behave like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is happening due to File System Tunneling in windows. There are options to disable/configure it. You can get more info regarding this from this link [support.microsoft.com](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/172190).

Innorder to counteract to this in java way, you can set file created time(file attribute) immediately after creation of file as in the code below.

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        final String FILE_PATH = "d:\\test.txt";
        FileUtils.deleteQuietly(new File(FILE_PATH));
        FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(FILE_PATH, false);
        fileWriter.append(new Date().toString());
        fileWriter.close();
        setFileCreationTime(FILE_PATH);

    }

    public static void setFileCreationTime(String filePath) throws IOException {
        Path path = Paths.get(filePath);
        FileTime fileTime = FileTime.fromMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        /* Changing the Created Time Stamp */
        Files.setAttribute(path, "basic:creationTime", fileTime,
                LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS);
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @SintoKltteera perfect answer 
Thanks for help
one little question is there same issue with other os for e.g unix,mac....
because while i search then i found unix os not storing creation time!!!!

Answer (score 4):

It's a NTFS issue. The system is caching file info, reusing it when you recreate the file.

See Remarks section in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.getcreationtime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

> NTFS-formatted drives may cache information about a file, such as file creation time, for a short period of time. As a result, it may be necessary to explicitly set the creation time of a file if you are overwriting or replacing an existing file.

Regards.

PS: You can use these commands to see it w/o using Java code:

```
del test.txt

echo test > test.txt

dir /TC test.txt
```

Comment: +1 for your effort to find out solution for me
That may be a reason
but while deleting and creating file from windows using file explore then why correct creation time is there
at that time is OS use different function.

please explain.

Comment: I don't how file explorer works nor how it deals with filesystem, but let try creating a .bat file with these commands:
    del test.txt  echo test > test.txt
dir /TC test.txt
and you can see that it's not a Java issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are not deleting the file before writing in it.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't delete the file before re-creating it, then you only modify it.

Answer (score 0):

You are appending to the file that was created on the date given, this is not creating a new file (which would give you a created date). What you are going to want to do is copy the contents of the original file to something (e.g. an array) delete the file then write a new one with all the original contents plus what you wanted to append.

Although your description implies this is not what you wanted this code to do, what you description implies is you want to delete the old file and only have the new contents, in which case you would do the following:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        File f=new File("d:\\inbox\\json\\test.txt");
        if (f.exists()) {
            f.delete();
        }
        f.createNewFile();
        FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter("d:\\inbox\\json\\test.txt", false);
        fileWriter.write(new Date().toString());
        fileWriter.close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `createNewFile()` call does not delete an existing file, it just creates a new one of one does not exist.

You need to do:

```
if (f.exists()) {
    f.delete();
}
```

Comment: i try that but same problem

Answer (score 0):

I haven't exactly Tried this yet. But I believe it is because your File object isn't being Garbage Collected.

```
File f = new File("test.txt");
if(f.exists()){
f.delete();
}
```

Now this is really Important. You wan't to create a new file. That doesn't allocate to that same memory address after you've delted the first.

```
File f2 = new File("test.txt");
f2.write bla bla.
```

Comment: I tried to set `f=null` and then run garbage collector using `System.gc()` but still same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I expect that your code misses to delete the file and then just appends to the not-deleted file. To check this, i would recommend to change the code

```
FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter("d:\\inbox\\json\\test.txt", false);
fileWriter.append(new Date().toString());
fileWriter.close();
```

to

```
System.out.println("Exists: " + Files.exists(Paths.get("d:\\inbox\\json\\test.txt"));
FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter("d:\\inbox\\json\\test.txt", false);
fileWriter.append(new Date().toString());
fileWriter.close();
```

If you see `Exists: true` in your console thats why you have the problem.

Comment: @faith OP is Exists: false
and commons-io's  FileUtils.deleteQuietly deletes file

Comment: looks like you have a problem on your filesystem maybe? your code works for me. have you tried with another file? do you use ntfs for your drive?

Comment: @faith yes i tried with different different file

and i have `NTFS` file system.