# DateCreated glitch? How to identify if overwriting

Tags: vba, ms-access, vbscript, filesystemobject

As part of an auto-update macro, I have a copy of an Access FrontEnd on the local drive which when opened, checks to see if the file on the server has a newer CreatedDate.  If it is newer, my code currently uses fileSystemObject to CopyFile and overwrites the local drive version (filename remains the same).

The problem I am having however is that when this is done, the 'date created' does not change to that of the newer file and so continually loops as the old file is closed and the new one opened - which checks for updates based on date created...  I even tried using kill on the local file and waiting 10 seconds before doing the Copyfile command but even then it appears with the deleted file's creation date.

When I get back to the office I'm going to try copying the file from the server to the local drive without renaming it, deleting the original local drive file, then copying the newly created file so I can rename it back to the original name (the name should not be changed so that any shortcuts will still work).

Has anyone come across this before and found a solution?  Am I missing something obvious that would 'refresh' the created date of the file?

**EDIT**
I think this is pretty close to what I had.

```
Dim strSource As String, strDest As String, strOrigDB As String, strSvrDB As String
Dim varOldDB As Variant, varNewDB As Variant, fso As Object

Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")

strSource = "\\192.168.1.2\Data\svrDatabase"
strSvrDB = "AnyOldName.mde" 
strDest = "C:\myFolder\myDatabase"
strOrigDB = "KeepMyName.mde"

varOldDB = (strDest & "\" & strOrigDB)
varNewDB = (strSource & "\" & strSvrDB)
If fso.getfile(varOldDB).DateCreated < fso.getfile(varNewDB).DateCreated Then
    Kill strDest & "\" & strOrigDB
    Excel.Application.Wait Now() + TimeValue("00:00:05")
    fso.copyfile (strSource & "\" & strSvrDB), (strDest & "\" & strOrigDB), True
    'open new database version
    ShellExecute 0, "Open", (strDest & "\" & strOrigDB), "", "", 1
    DoCmd.Quit
End If
```

I was originally using date modified, but noticed that as soon as the Front end opened, this would get renewed and would therefore always be a newer date value than the server file.

**EDIT**
After thinking about this, and hoping my logic hasn't completely broken down, it would be best if I had a shortcut for the user to click on, but instead of opening the Frontend, it opens a script file that checks for an update.  If there is an update, then it deletes the local Frontend and copies the server one (which should be named differently to the original) to the local folder - then opens the new frontend.

This would mean that the datecreated being checked is always going to be updated on copy to the local folder and the kill will work because the file has not been opened.  I am still a little wary of using lastdatemodified incase a user has the database open when an update is created - the Frontend contains tables used in searches which I believe will alter the modified date of the Frontend.  In this scenario the local date modified would still be greater than a new frontend on the server.

Comment: Hard to make any suggestions without seeing your existing code.

Comment: I agree with Tim Williams. Also, are you sure that your copy is succeeding? It sounds like it might just be failing quietly. And the code that is doing the copying is not in the database is it?

Comment: Sorry, at home right now and code is on my work computer.  I'll see if I can remember it and post it.  Copy is definitely succeeding - I even stepped through the code with the folder open.  File gets deleted, pause, copyfile puts new file in but the datecreated is from the deleted file, not the new one.  The code doing the copying is part of the Autoexec for the frontend - first thing that gets run as soon as the frontend is opened.  The backend is on the cloud so not opening a connection to that with this macro.  Going to get some code to put up now - I thought this would be a known issue.

Comment: It still sounds like you are using code on local disk to copy the file from the server over **itself** which will never succeed. You need an "external" script to do the checking & copying before then launching the front-end. Your shortcut then runs the script.

Comment: I never thought of that!!  I suppose I could amend my code above so that the condition is tested and if true, shellexecute could open a file (and close the current one) that will do the copying.  Does that sound feasible?

Comment: The way I have gotten DateCreated updates to save was to delete the directory containing the file. I have a database that distributes to users, but when copying from the server, the date created would remain the same at the destination. Deleting the directory works every time. It has to do with the way the file system stores file information. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20884521/date-created-is-not-going-to-change-while-delete-file-and-then-create-file

Answer (score 1):

You should be using Date Modified. That's when the file was last changed.

This is what helps says about times.

> Timestamps are updated at various times and for various reasons. The only guarantee about a file timestamp is that the file time is correctly reflected when the handle that makes the change is closed.

So try closing all files before comparing times.

Also From https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/172190

> When a name is removed from a directory (rename or delete), its short/long name pair and creation time are saved in a cache, keyed by the name that was removed. When a name is added to a directory (rename or create), the cache is searched to see if there is information to restore. The cache is effective per instance of a directory. If a directory is deleted, the cache for it is removed.

Also coping from an untrusted source will change last modified for sure.

Also there are rules for copy versus move.

Also files need to be wholey within Windows eco system for windows rules to apply for sure.

Comment: I suppose I shouldn't be running the code to kill a file while still in the file.  ChipsLetten just pointed that out.  That cache section you posted doesn't thrill me too much  :)  Looks like it may be a little difficult to work around.  Many thanks for the reply.